# Show that $ \mathbb{E}[X] < \infty \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}[X>n] < \infty $ for random variable $X$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable taking values in $\mathbb{N}$.

Show that
$
\mathbb{E}[X] < \infty \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}[X>n] < \infty
$.

I am not that good at math, but could you please explain to me why this does not work the way I think it does .. I am going to *speak loud* such that you can follow my thoughts.

This is a sum over all probabilities for $ X > n $:

$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}[X>n] $

This is the **general** definition of the expected value:

$ \mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_ip_i $

a weighted sum over all probabilites of a RV $X$.

Therefore:

$\mathbb{E}[x] = n_1 \mathbb{P}[X > n_1] + n_2 \mathbb{P}[X > n_2] + ... + n_\infty \mathbb{P}[X > n_\infty] $

**And this is what I want to know if this would make sense:**

Because $ n_1 \mathbb{P}[X > n_1] = n_1 \sum_{j=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}[([X= j + n_1] $
we can write:

\begin{align} 
\mathbb{E}[x] &= n_1 \sum_{j=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}[([X= j + n_1] + n_2 \sum_{j=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}[([X= j + n_2] + .. +  n_\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}[([X= j + n_\infty]  \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}[X = j + n] \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{j=n+1}^\infty \mathbb{P}[X = j] \\
&= \sum_{j=2}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^j \mathbb{P}[X = j] \\
&= \sum_{j=2}^\infty j * \mathbb{P}[X = j] = \mathbb{E}[X]
\end{align}

And this makes sense in my eyes since it is given that $ X > n$ and therefore $\mathbb{E}[X]$ must start with $j=2$ here. Unfortunatelly I was told that I can not write this since I do not follow the definition of the *expected value* whereas I think that I do.

Can anyone explain to me where I am making the mistake?

Comment: Say for example $X$ is the constant $1$.  Then $\mathbb E[X]=1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}[X>n] = 0$.  Although they are not equal, they are both $< \infty$

Comment: This step is wrong: "Therefore: $\mathbb{E}[x] = n_1 \mathbb{P}[X > n_1] + n_2 \mathbb{P}[X > n_2] + .. n_\infty \mathbb{P}[X > n_\infty] $". And I wonder where the = sign just before the first double sum comes from.

Comment: Why is this wrong, could you explain that please?

Comment: For example, if P(X=2)+P(X=3)=1, the sum is 2P(X=3) and E(X)=2P(X=2)+3P(X=3). (And please use @.)

Comment: @Did sorry.. I already feel a little stupid but why is *"if P(X=2)+P(X=3)=1, the sum is 2P(X=3)"* and *"E(X)=2P(X=2)+3P(X=3)"* ?

Comment: ?? There are only two points where P(X=x) is not zero, x=2 and x=3. Can't you compute the sum in your post, in this almost trivial case?

Comment: But I have a question myself: where did you find the "formula" $\sum\limits_xxP(X\gt x)$ for $E(X)$?

Comment: @Did I think I never stated that. What I say is $ \sum_{j=2}^\infty j * \mathbb{P}[X = j] = \mathbb{E}[X] $ you mean that?

Comment: At least twice, actually: this is written in your post (just after "Therefore") and you repeat it in a comment to @Frank's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ takes values in $\mathbb{N}$,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}[X]
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1)\overbrace{(\mathrm{P}[X\gt k]-\mathrm{P}[X\gt k+1])}^{\mathrm{P}[X=k+1]}\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^N(k+1)\mathrm{P}[X\gt k]-\sum_{k=0}^{N+1} k\mathrm{P}[X\gt k]\right)\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^N\mathrm{P}[X\gt k]-\color{#C00000}{\lim_{N\to\infty}(N+1)\mathrm{P}[X\gt N+1]}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\mathrm{P}[X\gt k]
\end{align}
$$
If $\mathrm{E}[X]\lt\infty$, then the sum for $\mathrm{E}[X]$ converges, and therefore, its tail must vanish
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=N}^\infty(k+1)(\mathrm{P}[X\gt k]-\mathrm{P}[X\gt k+1])\\
&\ge\lim_{N\to\infty}(N+1)\sum_{k=N}^\infty(\mathrm{P}[X\gt k]-\mathrm{P}[X\gt k+1])\\[6pt]
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}(N+1)\mathrm{P}[X\gt N]\\[10pt]
&\ge\color{#C00000}{\lim_{N\to\infty}(N+1)\mathrm{P}[X\gt N+1]}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I think it is important to note for a complete answer that the infinite sum can be rearranged because it is absolutely convergent.

Comment: @CalvinKhor: I have been a bit more precise; hopefully, not at the expense of clarity.

Answer (score 1):

On the wikipedia article on expectation you can find a proof of $E(X) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X>n)$. From here it follows immediately that one of these expressions is finite if and only if the other one is.

Comment: I know that proof but my question asks why it can be done like I am doing this - because I think it is basically the same but was told that it's not and I wonder why.

Comment: OK, I really don't understand. The sort of thing you are writing is exactly how the equality in my answer is proved. So if you understand the proof on wikipedia you should be happy. The exact details of what you have written in your question don't really make any sense at all.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but I was told me that I couldn't write it like this: $ \mathbb{E}[x] = n_1 \mathbb{P}[X > n_1] + n_2 \mathbb{P}[X > n_2] + ... + n_\infty \mathbb{P}[X > n_\infty] = \sum_{j=2}^\infty j * \mathbb{P}[X = j] $ (which is what I tried to show here). "Did" commented on my question claiming that this is wrong. If this is wrong then why is it wrong? (to be honest I don't get his explaination either)

Comment: Firstly what on earth does $ \cdots +  n_{\infty}P(X > n_{\infty}) $ even mean? This is a meaningless way of treating infinite sums.

Comment: And I would be interested to know what your reasoning behind the first equality you right is...? Where does this come from? It's hard to say why it isn't right, because it's just totally untrue.

Comment: Maybe I should have stated somehwere that $ \{n_1, n_2,..,n_\infty \} = \{ 1,2,..,\infty \} \epsilon \mathbb{N} $ so if we'd talk about a die we had $ \mathbb{E}[X] = n_1 P[X = 1] + n_2 P[X = 2].. = 1 * \frac{1}{6} + 2 * \frac{1}{6} + .. = 3.5 $

Comment: You claim $\infty \in \mathbb{N}$. This is simply not how you talk about infinite sums.