# Show that: $\mathbb E(U) = \sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb N} \mathbb P(U>k)$

Tags: probability

Given $(\Omega, \mathbb F, \mathbb P)$ is a probability space and $U : \Omega \to \mathbb N$ is a random variable. Show that: $\mathbb E(U) = \sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb N} \mathbb P(U>k)$.

$$\mathbb E(U) = \sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb N} \mathbb P(U>k) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb P(U = k+i) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb P(U = k+i) $$
$$ =\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\big[1-\sum\limits_{u=0}^{i-1} \mathbb P(U = u) \big] = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \big[n - \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} (n-i) \mathbb P(U=i) \big]$$
$$= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \big[n - n \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \mathbb P(U=i) + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} i \mathbb P(U=i) \big]$$

If I can show that: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \big[n - n \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} \mathbb P(U=i) \big] = 0$, then it's done. But the expression inside the limit is of the form $0 \times \infty$. What should I do?

This problem has been solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736491/show-that-mathbbex-infty-longleftrightarrow-sum-n-1-infty-mathbb) , but I just want do it on my own.

Comment: The expression inside the limit is $nP(U\geqslant n)$ and, by dominated convergence, its convergence to zero is implied by (actually, equivalent to) the fact that $E(U)$ is finite.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here you are a different approach, using [Abel's lemma](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Abel_lemma) (the converse of integration by parts for series).

By definition,

$$E(U) = \lim_{n\to \infty}\bigg(\sum_{k=0}^{n}kP(U=k)\bigg) = \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}} kP(U=k)$$

Now we apply Abel's lemma on the original series (to clarify, according to the reference, $a_k=P(U>k-1)$ and $b_k=1$, and hence $B_k=k$), so that we obtain
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n P(U>k-1) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k\cdot \big(P(U>k-1)-P(U>k)\big) + n\cdot P(U>n-1).
$$

We note that 
$$P(U>k-1)-P(U>k)=P(U=k).$$
Thus, we can write

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n P(U>k-1) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k\cdot P(U=k) + n\cdot P(U>n-1).
$$

Taking the limit as $n\to \infty$ and noting that $nP(U>n-1)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, as it was pointed out in the comments, does the work.

Comment: Different? $ $ $ $